# OpenCL: How to distribute a calculation on different devices without multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, opencl, openmp

Following my [former post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301270/opencl-comparing-the-time-required-to-add-two-arrays-of-integers-on-available-p) about comparing the time required to do a simple array addition job (C[i]=A[i]+B[i]) on different devices, I improved [the code](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/628a046040c302f507c81fd0568d8b34) a little bit to repeat the process for different array length and give back the time required:

[image]
 <sup>*The X axis is the array length in logarithm with a base 2 and Y is the time in logarithm with base 10. As it can be seen somewhere between 2^13 and 2^14 the GPUs become faster than the CPU. I guess it is because the memory allocation becomes negligible in comparison to the calculation. (GPI1 is a typo I meant GPU1).*</sup>

Now hoping [my C-OpenCL code](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/628a046040c302f507c81fd0568d8b34) is correct I can have an estimation of the time required to do an array addition on different devices: f1(n) for CPU, f2(n) for the first GPU and f3(n) for the second GPU. If I have an array job with a length of n I should theoretically be able to divide it into 3 parts as n1+n2+n3=n and in a way to satisfy the f1(n1)=f2(n2)=f3(n3) and distribute it on three devices on my system to have the fastest possible calculation. I think I can do it using lets say OpenMP or any other multithreading method and use the cores of my CPU to host three different OpenCL tasks. That's not what I like to do because:

1. It is a wast of resources. Two of the cores are just hosting while could be used for calculation
2. It makes the code more complicated.
3. I'm not sure how to do it. I'm now using the Apple Clang compiler with `-framework OpenCL` to compile the code, but for OpenMP I have to use the GNU compiler. I don't know how to both OpenMP and OpenCL on one of these compilers.

Now I'm thinking if there is any way to do this distribution without multithreading? For example if one of the CPU cores assigns the tasks to the three devices consequentially and then catches the results in the same (or different) order and then concatenate them. It probably needs a little bit of experimenting to adjust for the timing of the task assignment of the subtasks, but I guess it should be possible.

I'm a total beginner to the OpenCL so I would appreciate if you guys could help me know if it is possible and how to do it. Maybe there are already some examples doing so, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** I have also posted this question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gpgpu/comments/8j5zgi/opencl_how_to_distribute_a_calculation_on/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenCL/comments/8j624a/how_to_distribute_a_calculation_on_different/) on Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as its read implicitly tells you the solution should be concurrent (asynchronous) thus you require to add the results from three different devices at same time, otherwise what you will do is to run a process first on device A, then device B and then device C (better to run a single process on the fastest device), if you plan to efficiently learn to exploit OpenCL programming (either on mCPU/GPUs) you should be comfortable to do Asynchronous programming (indeed multi threaded).

Comment: So there is no way for the host to go and assign a new task to a different device while the former devices are doing their business? only the assignment and catching will be sequential.

Comment: Sure you can, the OpenCL enqueue API is asynchronous. You can start work on GPU, then do work on CPU while GPU is busy.